# Spark - copy a field using df.schema.copy functions for another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a schema using existing df field.

Consider this example dataframe

```
scala> case class prd (a:Int, b:Int)
defined class prd

scala> val df = Seq((Array(prd(10,20),prd(15,30),prd(20,25)))).toDF("items")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [items: array<struct<a:int,b:int>>]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
```

I need one more field "items_day1" similar to "items" for df2. Right now, I'm doing it like below which is a workaround

```
scala> val df2=df.select('items,'items.as("item_day1"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [items: array<struct<a:int,b:int>>, item_day1: array<struct<a:int,b:int>>]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- item_day1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- b: integer (nullable = false)


scala>
```

But how to get that using the df.schema.add() or df.schema.copy() functions?.

EDIT1:

I'm trying like below

```
val (a,b) = (df.schema,df.schema) // works
a("items")  //works
b.add(a("items").as("items_day1")) //Error..
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what your actual goal is.  If you want to add another column with the same type and data as the existing column, your "workaround" seems perfectly fine.  Method [schema.add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType@add(name:String,dataType:String,nullable:Boolean,comment:String):org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) simply creates a new schema of `StructType` with the added column structure.

Comment: Is it possible to get that using the df.schema.copy(...)..something like how we copy/paste and reuse them

Comment: Just updated the question with my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new field to your DataFrame schema (which is of [StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)) with the same structure but a different top-level name of the existing field, you can copy the [StructField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField) with a modified StructField member `name`, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class prd (a:Int, b:Int)

val df = Seq((Array(prd(10,20), prd(15,30), prd(20,25)))).toDF("items")

val schema = df.schema
// schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
//   StructField(items, ArrayType(
//     StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,false), StructField(b,IntegerType,false)
//   ), true), true)
// )

val newSchema = schema.find(_.name == "items") match {
  case Some(field) => schema.add(field.copy(name = "items_day1"))
  case None        => schema
}
// newSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
//   StructField(items, ArrayType(
//     StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,false), StructField(b,IntegerType,false)
//   ), true), true),
//   StructField(items_day1, ArrayType(
//     StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,false), StructField(b,IntegerType,false)
//   ), true), true)
// )
```

Comment: yes.. something like this.. how to pass as "items" instead of 0 in your answer?

Comment: ````schema.filter(_.name=="items").copy(name="items2")```` is giving error

Comment: @stack0114106, `filter` returns a collection.  You can use `find` to return an Option, as shown in the revised answer.

Comment: Yes.. you figured it out!.. great.. now I'm able to run ````df.schema.add(df.schema.find(_.name=="items").head.copy(name="items_day1"))````

Comment: pls add above also to the answer.. btw wrapping with default is good!..

Comment: I've modified the solution to avoid having to provide a default which might not be applicable in some cases.